# Borders of tables

Tags: tables

I have been working on my first LateX report, and everything works fine, except tables. It seems that some of the lines appear and other don't (In all my tables). I have tried adding and removing spaces, but nothing seems to work. Any idea why?

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{Maroon!10}{Maroon!20}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
\textbf{Material } & \textbf{Reflectivity ($\rho$)} & \textbf{Price (kg)}\\\hline
    Copper         & $0.75$ &  6.497US\textdollar\\\hline
Gold           & $0.76 \pm 0.03$ & 44000US\textdollar\\\hline
Various aluminum surfaces - range  & $0.82 - 0.92 $ & 1.716US\textdollar\\\hline
Anodized aluminum    & $0.82 \pm 0.05$ & 1.716US\textdollar\\\hline
Silver (unstable as a front surface mirror) & $0.94 \pm 0.02$ & 680US\textdollar\\\hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Specular reflectance values for different reflector materials (prices March 2014)}
\label{tab:fb4}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This may just be a viewer issue. What if you try zooming in, or using another viewer?

Comment: Indeed you are right! If I zoom into 300% it appears. Will this be a problem when printing the report, or will the lines always appear on the print?

Comment: I think they will appear, but that should be easy to figure out -- just print a test page.

Comment: You can circumvent this issue increasing the thickness of the border. Insert the line `\arrayrulewidth=1pt` inside the table.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I tried printing it and there it does display the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would leave an answer in case someone has a similar problem, instead of having to read through all the comments.

It seems to be a problem with the viewer. If I zoom in to 300% I can finally see all the lines. This does not affect the print. When printing the page, all lines appear.

In case it annoys you, you can always changethe border thickness with:

```
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
```